# laravel modal delete confirmation does not go to destroy route

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

When I run this code with the modal dialog script commented out, I see my controller message pop up. When I try it with the script, the modal pop up appears but clicking ok or cancel does nothing. I suspect that this is something to do with the "attr('action')" but i couldn't find documentation for it and am not sure how to get it to route to the controller. I tried changing 'action' to 'destroy' and 'delete' but that didn't work.

```
          <td> {{Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id)))}} 
               {{Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger'))}}
               {{Form::close()}}
          </td>
```

script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn-danger').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     url = $(this).parent().attr('action');
     BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?', function(result){
       if(result) {
         $.ajax(url);
       }
     });
   });
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    print_r($id);
//       User::find($id)->delete();
//      return View::make('hello');
        Response::json(['message'=>'Delete was successful']);

}
```

In my routes I have

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

running php artisan routes it shows

```
URI: DELETE users/{users} | Name: users.destroy | Action: UserController@destroy
```

Changing the jquery line as shown below will proceed to the controller message but the modal confirmation is now missing.

```
url = $(this).parent().attr('action');
BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?', function(result){
if(result) {
   $.ajax({url:url, 
           type:"DELETE",
           success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert(data.message + textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);},
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Failure: ' + textStatus + ". Error: " + errorThrown);}
           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your Routes.php file look like?

Ensure you have `Route::delete('users/{id}', ['uses' => 'UsersController@destroy', 'as'=>'users.destroy']);`

Secondly if you are using ajax you need to make sure you define the 'type' option for ajax to ensure it's set to `type: 'DELETE'` otherwise jQuery.ajax() will use 'POST' by default.  See here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Edit:
Just pointing out that the 'action' attribute just points the form to the URL it should post to, it does not define the METHOD (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) it should use.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the jquery line to set the type to DELETE and the action to delete and it works now.

Comment: actually I spoke to soon, inserting that line broke the the modal confirmation buts proceeds to display the controller popup message

Comment: Not sure if that jquery change works.  Try `$.ajax({url: url, type :"DELETE"});`  Also check see what result is actually returning when you cancel the confirm.

Comment: I used some alert boxes to see that I am getting 'result=true' for the confirm box. However the "url=undefined". I haven't been able to figure out how to form it properly.

Comment: By the way I see the issue in your JS.  You have $(this).parent().attr() where $(this) is refering to the form, if you remove .parent() it should work!

Comment: I fixed the js and the url (and corrected the attr back to 'action') and the url variable now says http://10.10.15.30:8000/users/10  however, after clicking yes, I am still on the same page/state. I don't get my popup debug message from my destroy function displaying...

Comment: You can RUN the js you pass back via echo automatically, thats not how that works, you need to run a 'success' and 'error' callback that fires that way.  You CAN pass back a message and have success fire an alert containing the msg.   
In your destroy method you should `return Response::json(['message'=>'Delete was successful']);` then in the ajax fire a callback on success like this:
`$.ajax().success(function($data, $textStatus, $jqXHR) { alert(data.message); });`

Comment: Thanks I added your callback with some changes as shown in my edit. It comes up with 'undefinedsuccess'. However it will delete my record now if I uncomment the delete line but I need to refresh the page to see it update :( any idea how to get it to show the update automatically? do I need to send an update command to the page?

Comment: You should just hop on #laravel IRC on freenode.net and look for me in the channel (same username) I can probably help you better there than replying via comments here.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! My initial problem is solved so I won't bother you anymore with stuff I should probably be able to figure out on my own. I will check out #laravel on IRC though thanks!